# Manipulate objects in an array to include an array of other values in found in sibling objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that looks like this (simplified):

```
[
  {
    name: 'Store1',
    price: ['10'],
    somethingElse: null
  },
  {
    name: 'Store2',
    price: ['5'],
    somethingElse: 6
  },
  {
    name: 'Store2',
    price: ['15'],
    somethingElse: 6
  },
]
```

I need to turn it into this:

```
[
  {
    name: 'Store1',
    price: ['10'],
    somethingElse: null
  },
  {
    name: 'Store2',
    price: ['5', '15'],
    somethingElse: 6
  },
]
```

So for each object where the `name` is the same, it takes the `price`'s for all of them and puts them in an array, and reduces amount of entries with the same `name` to one.

It needs to work for a much longer array, and work with many `name`'s.

Let's assume that everything other than the `price` will be the same in each object that has the same `name`.

I have tried for too long using `array.reduce` but with no luck.

Comment: Are you able to share what you've tried with `array.reduce()` so that we can help show you where you went wrong?

Comment: It was similar to shutsmans's answer below, but I was not using `.find` and `.map` inside the `reduce` properly, probably due to insufficient understanding of the accumulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const input = [
  {
    name: 'Store1',
    price: ['10'],
    somethingElse: null
  },
  {
    name: 'Store2',
    price: ['5'],
    somethingElse: 6
  },
  {
    name: 'Store2',
    price: ['15'],
    somethingElse: 6
  },
]

const output = input.reduce((a,c) => {
if(a.find(i => i.name === c.name)) { // Check if 'name' already exist 
    return a.map(el => el.name === c.name ? ({...el, price: [...el.price, ...c.price]}) : el) // updating price for existed name
} else {
    return [...a, c] // no such name, should add to ouput result
}
}, [])

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use grouping by hash approach:

```js
const data = [{"name":"Store1","price":["10"],"somethingElse":null},{"name":"Store2","price":["5"],"somethingElse":6},{"name":"Store2","price":["15"],"somethingElse":6}];

const result = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  acc[obj.name] ??= obj;
  if (!acc[obj.name].price.includes(...obj.price)) 
    acc[obj.name].price.push(...obj.price);

  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```